# Как пишется слово "по одному"?

Tags: орфография

В словарях указаны две формы: по одному и по-одному, но все ли об этом знают?  Почему во многих текстах используется только дефисное написание "по-одному"? Может быть, правило менялось?

(1) В этих примерах должно быть раздельное написание:

Братия скита должна была жить в избушках-кельях по-одному.  Его песня звала, вела и уводила ― по-одному из толпы ― в горы, в ясность, в чистоту, в сторону от коллективного разума…

(2) А здесь всё правильно:

По-одному пахли мох и вода, по-другому― неясно и терпко― осоки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вера, справочник Розенталя и Академический справочник предлагают раздельное написание. 
Раздельно пишутся сочетания предлога по с собирательными числительными, напр.: ***по двое, по трое, по пятеро.***
[Как пишется «по одному](http://yandex.ru/clck/jsredir?from=yandex.ru%3Bsearch%2F%3Bweb%3B%3B&text=&etext=695.Kg3MH-VEJGNcqLHNRFVwM4ekQNSXMT-NxvLfCyBSrEVyW7ROV4GmgMyH2lymxJEeLu-GG7o-L0fdMp-K5dqxQs4RC7ew1ZveKd9rrzzf9HU4pIbUh-DSEU7lax21jC1j.91fdc0f6088ce7658ee7d6334438ad35019ba837&uuid=&state=PEtFfuTeVD5kpHnK9lio9cUEbBkAQk_OhAzHcv9PulIpF4ylKJ2-qA&data=UlNrNmk5WktYejR0eWJFYk1LdmtxbXh5YzdQbXJyR3o3dllDVzBjUjNnM2VEcUV3ejhHNW91UUZRX19LbER1SlpsdXhmR2QyOTAyQ0RQYU5YNC0yazZOY3pGbTlkMEMtVVVadVZ0b1QtZUhaY0x2RHkzbU9sSEtab3VFLWI4RU1pUnlrMkkxam1kYw&b64e=2&sign=8b81ab48063e40b3693c1b33abc4a204&keyno=0&cst=AiuY0DBWFJ7IXge4WdYJQYtNprRPFzufqudLJZKAOLwoDTdQIxazSeWiChev90bYFecXuYsoEIIG-uSzTIEBkz0jmmpFONAqhO-AdSI9CTX8fDXGob1yS35LAMpgs9rozvKRh8POL_KO-QPqqnYgZHuARAWPvR7TAs83U12Hn7xpPp6JERxQVoIIgh5A4cAcrr1kvaM4VBskQmI8KgfD7ClGwBtj7Vn2&ref=cM777e4sMOAycdZhdUbYHpMQ80108_UCHgI4h6Y0hbtoes4Cfdh8gElSHGDfKYZD7zPxUVb-tt50IXb1dPYdTOQXTag6CEW-HWcrHmNyXJ2ErjMso2EcLXju8xuJeTJH_QvyFF5-H9byYAlVJ5kEFB8Los-F2auIsfJoIYB6xexQaH7JQI0Im4Y5sgRqqWqnJ4InG6LDqafXjIXiRReQHGGq37pzRKQoGfRc3dGvQ1c_ucY8NRRHri6J-wRFuCA-CPFBFoDJs0rycZGzXuxsa7Bs6Qx033yvqzJfMNdlsXPTBRfsWjc5X8NR1g310SNGeATEmy8ZjKRVF4k9DkpHwU8chnHsB7sL75oEC9X-MQUf13JsJ2pEm4HWXffVSpTYGpF3ZsSmlI1Vh8QmvonMAdjJ7ZPSQFRLJW655JNtDR1frvkFbjBIsh5J1CGWVXQEXyVmGV1bIWoz2WNUnnGOl0JfDbQNSwNooLZ7V4mPaBUdryN7j2ECdSO7W4TH_7nkykzGmM9bGyhRy0PVQmeXN1z8N85OP53HivHN5_cpvD_NOBL69sxOMMbkWNUfOBgv_5gPhsHsFXFfCnurQ8wrDgFHB0YYTip7vNWX6HpClBZFr9iWZaBEqScEFie7HBM-v_PIYa5D7IuL2CgKIPG3MkRnGBm5yBJLotXIuJ493zLUYV53hhrcoo-RlVr2Jx6Ulo7sLSKgXBnCyrF7WOZyHyaFjxbfxfmPZOhUPUbv-K1lt9cOlP_FiwudoheG4uVa-pK9YKUzk7bYYgVN6B99TgC7czvHMWSYSPc0XDdUed59xXjMODjVwJVYooUDJafFwgMC8Os35oe2VAlVd8kRHlPWgpyKzF6BOuKdGUAOwf5o6I810IpkVAFe5uI4WSNmzv5uGWcRwqzdT07KjvMOhzCHKetC7QQ7GEG-w_K4yFeqikh8-K7Y8Xk8OjsLxl7mFMjJHDek3hagBaIRml0hKIFhU_XpEnAmLpkKynLaIJ-scBDGUk9Yn3WlckngAqHrykZxQstYL6OJw0m5hTzJWfuSSKIVUdJF66_KiTNpkEQl80z4C7WupPTWQmcJbLrWLmRWK8wLnojzimmqmX7gfQD_Xx79rVz17i6omokP0BDoHuNkozB1ryFMu-1AfkbmCT1CxwLZ-rmPA2cbibBWjbIimGHMETvVLFy3fH5zB0fXfD7oEkc7jl-Q_yDqg0CqWg-Wi3CFiVNdAgbAOE6tAtxiMcfv-HzmBUhxQQEYHVGz7WyuA-10AYPTb8VB2MWrlhtw5-y2fxQFZZWCWYt7xc9K7wVyjKCPnBLema5Ejp43o7ZHhn_YHf0MJKnu1mKy7CJ42GR2VPYolYQ7w1dUeNVpXfohhJYna7VuhD83_sN2QwpI6-B3tHCJN8yv5afTh-Nb1qKAunySGEvE_mXkIHZfLl8aTcczTtoG68c4zqA9jbkNPiCF26rV2znLgrG0oZecJ-dNgp2lLBYVMDR2ig&l10n=ru&cts=1432214290085&mc=4.2567963154085025)
Далее, в словаре Лопатина дается такое объяснение: по-одному, нареч.

> (сначала по-одному, а потом - по-другому)
>   по одному (поодиночке, следуя друг за другом)

Интересная статья и здесь:[Правописание наречий](http://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.portal-slovo.ru%2Fphilology%2F37385.php&ei=Qt1dVb6bEsWRsAH9hYOwCg&usg=AFQjCNHpZCmVeCXikcLEoTopXO1vaCBbIg&bvm=bv.93756505,d.bGg&cad=rjt)

Comment: Спасибо, Серж, интересная статья. Мне кажется, что навести порядок в применении дефиса можно только одним  способом, а именно обозначив смысловое содержание дефисного написания, в частности для наречий с предлогом ПО.  Особенно удивительны две современные узаконенные формы "по его и по-его". Поэтому  академический словарь "Слитно, раздельно или черед дефис" нужно просмотреть полностью, во избежание  других неожиданных "открытий".

Comment: Я с вами полностью согласен! Да и порядок нужен не только в применении дефиса. В современных правилах вообще разнобой.